# Register an interface with Autofac?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a class based on DbContext and it's generated automatically by the EF designer (currently using Database First). The DbContext is in its own assembly called 'Model'.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext {}
```

I also have code in another partial class and implementing an interface:

```
public interface IMyContext
{
    int Commit();
    Task<int> CommitAsync(CancellationToken ct);
}

public partial class MyContext : IMyContext {}
```

I also have a Unit of Work and generic repository. These classes are in another separater assembly called 'DAL'

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<TContext> : IDisposable where TContext : IMyContext
{
    int Commit();
    Task<int> CommitAsync(CancellationToken ct);
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class {}

public abstract class Repository<TContext, T> : IRepository<T> where TContext : IMyContext where T : class, IEntity
```

And finally I have my services, which are in yet another assembly called 'Services'.

```
public class LoginService : BaseService, ILoginService
{
    public LoginService(ILogService logService,
                        IUnitOfWork<IMyContext> unitOfWork) 
        : base(logService, unitOfWork) 
    { }
}
```

I need to register IMyContext with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MyContext))
       .As(typeof(IMyContext))
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

But if I do the above registration, I get an error that DbContext is not known. This is because I don't have (and don't want/need) a reference to Entity Framework in my WebApi project

Can I still register the above interface without requiring a reference to EF? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application

Answer (score 0):

Seems the error is because MyContext is not also registered as DbContext.

An alternative might be that you create an [Autofac module](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) that lives inside your DAL assembly and is responsible for the registrations related to `MyContext`. The Autofac registrations in your WebApi project now would consist of registering the module as opposed to registering the individual types.

This would mean you would need a reference to Autofac in your DAL assembly. Also, I'm not entirely familiar with Autofac's more recent versions, so I'm not sure if you'll run into issues trying to register an InstancePerRequest scope outside of a web project.

Comment: I ultimately removed DbContext as a constraint and added more methods to IMyContext which in turn call the DbContext's methods.